# How to know what current output a USB-C port can provide?

Tags: power, usb-c

I'm designing an electronic device that will plug into a USB-C port.  We need at least 7.5W (5V, 1.5A).  The USB-C spec says that not all ports support the 7.5W or 15W output, but that it's optional.  I know that a lot of ports will support that output, but I need to be able to know for various laptops what it is able to output.

**Is there an application or other method that a user can use to find out what current output the laptop's USB-C port(s) can provide?**

I've tried the device manager and (unless I'm missing something), it seems useless.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably the datasheet for the motherboard or chipset

Comment: See [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669591/how-to-know-what-current-output-a-usb-c-port-can-provide](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669591/how-to-know-what-current-output-a-usb-c-port-can-provide). Please do not ask the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: You can purchase a USB Power Delivery tester, which will give you both the (reported) capability of the port and the actual power being delivered. They can be expensive, though...

Answer (score 1):

The [USB Type-C specifications](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/designing-in-usb-type-c-and-using-power-delivery-for-rapid-charging) state:

- "A Dedicated Charging Port (DCP)... can supply currents up to 1.5 amps for a power delivery of 7.5 watts," shown by the D+ and D- lines being shorted.
- A Charging Downstream Port (CDP), also 1.5 A, "has 15 kΩ pull-down resistors necessary for D+ and D- communication, and internal circuitry that switches in during the charger detection phase. This internal circuitry allows the portable device to distinguish a CDP from other port types."

However, there appear to be many devices with *non-compliant* USB-C ports, so you may need to

- Provide a list of acceptable models on which you've checked your device (though a new version of a theoretically identical PC might have differing specs),
- or provide a port for an additional power supply.

If the extra design and implementation costs are acceptable, it might be useful to include a low power-on test that checks voltage drop when full load is applied.

Comment: I don't read the same thing out of the USB-C spec.  In the USB-C spec, it says
"Not all options will be available to the device from all host or hub ports – only the first two listed options are mandated by the base USB specifications and form the basis of USB Type-C Current at the Default USB Power level." with the first two listed options being USB 2.0 power (5V 500mA) and USB 3.2 power (5V 900mA).  It lists "USB Type-C Current @ 1.5 A" as an option that the USB-C port can provide, but my reading of it doesn't imply that a port that doesn't output 1.5A isn't compliant.

Comment: This is out of the USB Type-C Spec R2.0, August 2019, section 2.4 (and table 2-1).

Comment: And to clarify, the goal of my question is for me to figure out from the PC side what the port is able to provide.  Ideally, I'd be able to use some tool on the PC to see whether a USB-C port can provide default power (USB 2.0 or 3.2 power), 1.5A, 3A, or power delivery of some kind.

Comment: @mbengineer, That is correct... not *all* USB-C ports provide 1.5 A (or more). The answer stated, that those with specific D+ and D- configurations do. And the answer also states that *you* would need to provide a list of acceptable PC's, not from the PC system info.